# Unable to add labels to the x axis of my ggplot using scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason, I am unable to add a labels to the x axis of my ggplot. I'm using code that has worked in the past, but something isn't working out in this circumstance.

Here's my ggplot:

```
RussetPlotMrk <-ggplot(mrkRus,aes(x=Rate,y=number)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#52854C") +
 theme_grey(base_size = 20) +
 facet_wrap(~Variety,nrow=2) +
 scale_x_discrete(labels=c("125%", "100%", "75%", "50%", "75%50%")) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,by = 10), limits=c(0, 100))
```

And here's the head of my data:

```
dput(head(mrkRus))
structure(list(Variety = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Burbank 2018", 
"Burbank 2019", "Norkotah 2018", "Norkotah 2019", "Silverton 2018", 
"Silverton 2019"), class = "factor"), Rate = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L), total = c(66.02375756, 62.50788744, 62.55239864, 69.73401417, 
66.30070975, 64.552774), mrktotal = c(43.49463647, 38.12657119, 
33.94832803, 44.94819267, 40.02596308, 49.07424897), per = structure(c(18L, 
16L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 22L), .Label = c("17%", "19%", "21%", "23%", 
"28%", "30%", "32%", "34%", "42%", "43%", "47%", "49%", "50%", 
"54%", "60%", "61%", "64%", "66%", "70%", "72%", "73%", "76%", 
"77%", "78%"), class = "factor"), number = c(66L, 61L, 54L, 64L, 
60L, 76L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your variable rate are continuous (numeric) values, you need to pass them as a factor format in order to set your labels using `scale_x_discrete`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=as.factor(Rate),y=number)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#52854C") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 20) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety,nrow=2) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("125%", "100%", "75%", "50%", "75%50%")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,by = 10), limits=c(0, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't notice it wasn't a factor.

Comment: You're welcome ! Maybe it depends of how you load your dataset... Have a good continuation ;)